Vue app getting a _plugin-vue_export-helper 404 error when deployed
Trying to publish an app I'm building to my https://xxxx.github.io/ but am getting the error "GET https://xxxx.github.io/assets/_plugin-vue_export-helper-DlAUqK2U.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)", but only on certain pages.  Not sure what is different about the pages with the issue vs without.
Also not sure what this plugin even is.  I assume it must be inherited down the node_modules pool somewhere.  But, how do I get around this.  I assume it has something to do with the name starting with an underscore?  The file is there, but still 404ing.
Works perfectly fine when 'npm run dev'

Does it work locally? Where are you trying to host it? Try to narrow down why some pages crash by commenting out parts of the code.

Github does not allow files starting with _ by default. You can change this behaviour by adding a file called .nojekyll at the root of your project.
